# How can I access the node ID when writing PHP into a block?

Tags: blocks

I see that when I am creating a block through the drupal admin I can use PHP, in addition to plain text & html.  Is there a variable in scope that I can use to access the node id?

```
<?php echo my_custom_function( $node_id, $my_desired_class); ?>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) function which will get you the node object for the page, assuming of course your block is being displayed on a node page:

```
$node = menu_get_object();

if (isset($node->nid)) {
  $nid = $node->nid;
  echo my_custom_function($nid, $my_desired_class);
}
```